# Data structure for storing and searching the result of tournament

Tags: c++, data-structures

> There are 100 players p1, p2, ...... p100, Each player plays a match against every other player. You have to store the result of the matches that is the winner of each combination (Pi, Pj).

What data structure should I use for an efficient store and search of result?

Comment: and what data structure would you use ?

Comment: @Andrew I was thinking of some way of hashing so that at I have to go through, let's say, n/10 (n, here, is 4950) or less elements to acces the element I am looking for.

Comment: A mapping with a pair as key and the winning player as data might work.

Comment: @Jatin I think a binary tree map or a hash map are the best solutions. std::map of pair<int,int> to int works out of the box, hash map (unordered_map) would require a user provided hashing function. I updated my answer.

Comment: Think also what happens if you query the structure with (p83,p5)

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at associative containers, such as [std::map](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map). These allow you to store key-value pairs, with logarithmic look-up time. You could consider a map of index-pair-like objects, so that you can search the result like this:

```
int result = myMap[PairLikeType(i,j)];
```

where `i` and `j` are the indices of two players.

`std::map` is implemented as a binary search tree, but there are also hash table based maps around, for instance C++11's [std::unordered_map](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) (available in `tr1/unordered_map`, on gcc at least), or `boost::hash_map`.

You could implement this by defining your own index pair (or using `std::pair<int,int>`, for which less-than comparison is provided) as a key to the map, and maybe wrap this in a class with an accessor method allowing you to check, given a pair of indices:

```
struct ResultMap {
  int winnerID(int playerID1, int playerID2)
  {
    return m_map[std::make_pair(playerID1, playerID2)]; // or use map::find
                                                        // of you want to handle
                                                        // non-existent keys specially
  }
 private:
  std::map<std::pair<int,int>, int> m_map;
};
```

You could implement the above with an `std::unordered_map`, but you would have to provide your own hashing function for the `std::pair<int,int>`.

Comment: Are you intended to use std::multimap ? because, if one player won against multiple players,std::map will not be useful.

Comment: @Sachin very good point. I will remove the first option, and leave the map of pair-like objects one. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I would go with one dimensional array with clever function to compute the index.

I would structure the array as a array of packets:

```
0 
1  0
2  0 1
3  0 1 2
4  0 1 2 3 
//and so on
```

Where the first columns correspond to `i` player. The raw corresponds to `j` players which could play with i

Here is how the array looks in memory:
`||0|0 1|1 0 1|1 0 0 1|` //0,1 - bool results

Here is the function to compute the index. (it make have some mistakes like you have to add 1 to some index, but generally it is correct)

```
int index(int i, int j) // i = [0, 99], j = [0, 99]
{
    assert(i != j);
    if ( i < j) std::swap(i, j); //i should be maximum. i == j not considered

    int num_oponents = i;

    int pack_start_index = num_oponents * (num_oponents + 1) / 2; //sum of 1 + 2 + 3 + ... + num_oponents
    int pack_internal_index = j;

    return pack_start_index + pack_internal_index;
}
```

Nothing else except the required data (4950 items) is stored in that case

The idea of this solution is similar to 2d array, but without storing duplicates and self with self results.

Answer (score 0):

Did you consider 2-dimension array? If you need to store only result, then I think it will be the best choose.

Comment: That's inefficient. A 100X100 2d array will have 100,00 elements while we only need to store the result of 4950 matches.

Answer (score 0):

Take a 100x100 array.

Store the winner in each position

```
    p1 p2 p3  
 p1 0  p2 p1  
 p2 p2 0  p3 
 p3 p1 p3 0
```

Space complexity O(n^2)

Time complexity to store and query O(1)

Comment: but I do NOT need 10,000 elements. I only need to store the result of 4950(100C2) matches. It's wasteful of memory.